How to analyze furniture for digital reconstruction?
My end-goal is to take a single photo of a piece of common furniture (couch, chair, table) and create a 3d model from that. I'm a novice with deep learning as I've only done basic CNN's and such with existing datasets (mnist).
To get 3d data from a 2d image what will I need in my training set?
My best guess is that I'll need 3d models & raw textures with corresponding 2d renders from multiple various angles.
Am I on the right track?
EDIT -- adding project overview
My current high-level overview for this project looks like the following:
Prep

Assemble a set of 1000+ couches from various angles with backgrounds removed (opencv)
ShapeNet, ModelNet for common furniture geometry datasets

Segmentation

use Mask R-CC to segment cushions, arms, backrest, etc
DeepLab/HRNet for finer segmentation as needed

Object Detection / Classification

YOLOv5/v8 for detection/labeling
CNN for component detection

Depth Estimation

DenseDepth (mono) or PASMNet (stereo)

3D Reconstruction via Blender Python API

NeRF for 3d mesh/model generation
Meshlab for mesh refinement & optimization

Shape Completion and Occluded Part Estimation

VAE/GAN/DCGAN? for prediction from dataset
DeepSDF for signed distance functions to predict full 3d from partial input

Texture Mapping

MaterialGAN to synthesize textures from photos

A lot is assumed between milestones so constructive criticism is welcome
